# how to onUnbind AccessibilityService

Tags: accessibilityservice

I have created an ActivityMonitorService which extends AccessibilityService to capture TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED events. But when I force close my app, the phone restart all the time. The onUnbind() was called when the main activity onDestroy(),But every time after phone restart, the ActivityMonitorService restart and cause my phone restarted for some reasons. Give me some advice，please.

ActivityMonitorService.java

```
public class ActivityMonitorService extends AccessibilityService {
public static final String LOG_TAG = "ActivityMonitorService";
private MyBinder myBinder = new MyBinder();

public class MyBinder extends Binder {
    public ActivityMonitorService getService()
    {
        return ActivityMonitorService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
    super.onRebind(intent);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "--------onRebind--------");
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "--------onUnbind--------");
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "--------onCreate--------");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "--------onStartCommand--------");

    int i = super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    Log.e(LOG_TAG,"--------onStartCommand--------, i = " + i +",START_NOT_STICKY="+ START_NOT_STICKY);

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}


@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG,"onServiceConnected enter");
    super.onServiceConnected();

    //Configure these here for compatibility with API 13 and below.
    AccessibilityServiceInfo config = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    config.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED;
    config.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;
    config.notificationTimeout = 100;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
        //Just in case this helps
        config.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_INCLUDE_NOT_IMPORTANT_VIEWS;

    setServiceInfo(config);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG,"onServiceConnected");
}

@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG,"onAccessibilityEvent");
    if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED) {
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(
                event.getPackageName().toString(),
                event.getClassName().toString()
        );

        ActivityInfo activityInfo = tryGetActivity(componentName);
        boolean isActivity = activityInfo != null;
        if (isActivity)
            Log.i("CurrentActivity", componentName.flattenToShortString());
    }
}

private ActivityInfo tryGetActivity(ComponentName componentName) {
    try {
        return getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(componentName, 0);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onInterrupt() {}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "--------onDestroy--------");
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String LOG_TAG = "MainActivity";
public static int OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE = 1234;

private boolean isBoundMonitorService = false;
private ActivityMonitorService monitorService = null;//get minitor service through binder
private ActivityMonitorService.MyBinder myBinder = null;
private ServiceConnection monitorConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        Log.e(ActivityMonitorService.LOG_TAG, "------onServiceDisconnected---------");
        isBoundMonitorService = false;
    };

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        isBoundMonitorService = true;
        Log.e(ActivityMonitorService.LOG_TAG, "------onServiceConnected---------");
        //myBinder = (ActivityMonitorService.MyBinder)service;
        //monitorService = myBinder.getService();
    };
};


    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "no permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);
        }
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate");
    //WindowUtils.showPopupWindow(getApplicationContext());
    Intent ServiceIntent = new Intent(this, ServiceUtils.class);
    startService(ServiceIntent);

    Intent AndroidMonitorServiceIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityMonitorService.class);
    bindService(AndroidMonitorServiceIntent,monitorConnection,BIND_AUTO_CREATE);//
    Log.e(ActivityMonitorService.LOG_TAG, "------bindService---------");

    //finish();
}

@Override
protected  void onDestroy(){
    if(isBoundMonitorService)
    {
        Log.e(ActivityMonitorService.LOG_TAG, "------unbindService---------");
        unbindService(monitorConnection);
        isBoundMonitorService = false;
    }

    super.onDestroy();
    //Intent ServiceIntent = new Intent(this, ServiceUtils.class);
    //stopService(ServiceIntent);
    //finish();
}
```

}

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <service
        android:name=".util.ActivityMonitorService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
        android:enabled = "true"
        android:exported = "false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
            android:resource="@xml/accessibilityservice"/>
    </service>
```

### xml/accessibilityservice.xml

```
<accessibility-service
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowStateChanged"
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
android:accessibilityFlags="flagIncludeNotImportantViews"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"/>
```

### Add some logs

```
    05-24 08:32:44.989 8313-8313/? I/HwLauncher: Launcher  Launcher.onStart() cost 1 ms
05-24 08:32:44.989 6778-6814/? W/WindowManager: Attempted to remove non-existing token: android.os.Binder@342478f
05-24 08:32:44.989 8313-8313/? I/HwLauncher: Launcher onResume()
05-24 08:32:44.989 8313-8430/? E/HwLauncher: SettingsEx , no such field.
05-24 08:32:44.989 8313-8313/? I/HwLauncher: Launcher doResumeWork()
05-24 08:32:44.989 8313-8430/? W/HwLauncher: Clock getDataFormat the getSystemString failed.
05-24 08:32:44.990 6778-6814/? E/AndroidRuntime: *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: android.bg
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED dat=package:com.example.org.floatwindow flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.android.server.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerService$1@5de13ec
                                                     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:1235)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                                                     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.os.IBinder.unlinkToDeath(android.os.IBinder$DeathRecipient, int)' on a null object reference
                                                     at com.android.server.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerService$Service.unlinkToOwnDeathLocked(AccessibilityManagerService.java:3122)
                                                     at com.android.server.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerService$Service.onRemoved(AccessibilityManagerService.java:3113)
                                                     at com.android.server.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerService.removeServiceLocked(AccessibilityManagerService.java:1145)
                                                     at com.android.server.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerService.-wrap22(AccessibilityManagerService.java)
                                                     at com.android.server.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerService$Service.unbindLocked(AccessibilityManagerService.java:2385)
                                                     at com.android.server.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerService.updateServicesLocked(AccessibilityManagerService.java:1307)
                                                     at com.android.server.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerService.onUserStateChangedLocked(AccessibilityManagerService.java:1445)
                                                     at com.android.server.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerService.-wrap19(AccessibilityManagerService.java)
                                                     at com.android.server.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerService$1.onHandleForceStop(AccessibilityManagerService.java:343)
                                                     at com.android.internal.content.PackageMonitor.onReceive(PackageMonitor.java:388)
                                                     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:1222)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)?
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)?
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)?
                                                     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)?
```

Comment: Stack traces are infinitely more valuable than code...

Answer (score 0):

You don't start AccessibilityServices from activities.  Accessibility services are started from the

> Settings > Accessibility

area on the phone.  You cannot start an Accessibility Service in the way you are attempting.

Comment: Thanks for your advices, but I have configured  “Settings > Accessibility”. AccessibilityServices already start and can get events of TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED. The question is how to stop the service when app froce closed. I know the lifecycle of the AccessibilityServices is maintained by the android system, when configure “Settings > Accessibility”, the service is connected, but how to stop it when app close.

Comment: You can't.  Just like you can only start it in Accessibility settings, you can only shut it down here as well.